# how to make a list from ansible_facts with multiple hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to make a list with IP addresses of various hosts and then use this list in another task. My question is, how can I pick an IP (I need the public IP) from the output of each host and add it to a list? I need the IPs that do **not** start with `10.`.

Later, I need to use this list in another task.

I extract this information by running this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: facts
  become: true
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "The ip: {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
```

Later, I need to use this list in another task:

```yaml
- wait_for:
    host: "{{ item[0] }}"
    port: "{{ item[1] }}"
    state: started
    delay: 0
    timeout: 2
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  ignore_errors: no
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  register: result
  failed_when: not result.failed  
  with_nested:
    - [ IP LIST HERE]
    - [443,80,9200,9300,22,5432,6432]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access those values from the [`hostvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) right away, then use a [`reject`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reject) filter with a [`match`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) test in order to reject what you don't want to test for.

Which, in a `debug` task would gives:

```yaml
# note: ports list reduced for brevity 

- debug:
    msg: "I should wait for interface {{ item.0 }}:{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      hostvars
        | dict2items
        | selectattr('key', 'in', ansible_play_hosts)
        | map(attribute='value.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses', default=[])
        | flatten
        | reject('match', '10\..*')
        | product(_ports)
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0 }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  vars:
    _ports:
      - 22
      - 80
```

---

In my lab, this give:

```
ok: [ansible-node-1 -> localhost] => (item=172.18.0.3) => 
  msg: I should wait for interface 172.18.0.3:22
ok: [ansible-node-1 -> localhost] => (item=172.18.0.3) => 
  msg: I should wait for interface 172.18.0.3:80
ok: [ansible-node-1 -> localhost] => (item=172.18.0.4) => 
  msg: I should wait for interface 172.18.0.4:22
ok: [ansible-node-1 -> localhost] => (item=172.18.0.4) => 
  msg: I should wait for interface 172.18.0.4:80
```

Comment: Hi! @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for you reply.
I have this error with the "default" parameter in map _jinja2.exceptions.FilterArgumentError: Unexpected keyword argument 'default'_

if i delete _default=[]_ : Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.product object at 0x7f48a01ec040>

Comment: That's because, on old versions of Jinja, iterators are not cast back as list. Add a `| list` after the `product` filter, or better yet, upgrade to a supported version of Ansible.

Comment: Thanks! That worked (add | list). How can stored this IP's in var to use in other task?

Comment: Use the `set_fact` module.

Answer (score 1):

Try the example below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses')|
                 map('first')|list }}"
    ip_list_reject: "{{ ip_list|reject('match', '10\\.')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: network
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: ip_list
        - debug:
            var: ip_list_reject
        - wait_for:
            host: "{{ item.0 }}"
            port: "{{ item.1 }}"
            state: started
            delay: 0
            timeout: 2
          delegate_to: localhost
          register: result
          with_nested:
            - "{{ ip_list_reject }}"
            - [443, 80, 9200, 9300, 22, 5432, 6432]
      run_once: true
```